# How to send email by using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I developed a web-form for a blog, and I need to send its values to an email.

How can I send an email by using jQuery or JavaScript alone?

Answer (score 51):

The short answer is that you can't do it using JavaScript alone. You'd need a server-side handler to connect with the SMTP server to actually send the mail. There are many simple mail scripts online, such as this one for PHP:

[Simple PHP mail script](http://www.buildwebsite4u.com/advanced/php.shtml)

Using a script like that, you'd POST the contents of your web form to the script, using a function like this:

[jQuery.post](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post)

And then the script would take those values, plus a username and password for the mail server, and connect to the server to send the mail.

Comment: did anything change in last 10 years? Do modern browser allow sending emails by telnet-like connections to SMTP/IMAP servers? I found https://www.smtpjs.com/ but can't find any working example. I see an Email.send({}).then()  function, but can't understand how to read the response value

Comment: No, same story - you still need an SMTP server to send mail. It looks like smtpjs.com takes you to a page where you can sign up for an email-sending service.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it server-side with [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/).

Check out the popular [Nodemailer](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer) package. There are plenty of transports and plugins for integrating with services like **AWS SES** and **SendGrid**!

The following example uses SES transport (Amazon SES):

```
let nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
let aws = require("aws-sdk");
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  SES: new aws.SES({ apiVersion: "2010-12-01" })
});
```

Answer (score -3):

You can send mail by Jquery just follow these steps

Include this link : `<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>`

After that use this code:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
     Email.send({
    Host : "smtp.yourisp.com",
    Username : "username",
    Password : "password",
    To : 'them@website.com',
    From : "you@isp.com",
    Subject : "This is the subject",
    Body : "And this is the body"}).then( message => alert(message));});
```

Comment: Careful, the service that handles the script can intercept your messages, not saying it does but it's quite a risk