# How do I send an email using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, email

How do I send email using JavaScript?

I don't want to use mailto, because if I use mailto it will open an email client.

Comment: take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415205/how-to-send-email-by-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 6):

Can't be done. Sending e-mail only works on the server side. If all you're doing is sending e-mail, a quick [PHP](http://php.net) script would likely do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Matchu. Sending email requires server side languages and Javascript is client side languages. In this case, the best way would be to use PHP. When you'll PHP you've lot's of the option to send an email how you like. Here's the relevant example which you can use to send an email by using the PHP default `mail()` function.

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```