# send email after validation

Tags: javascript

hi i am new enough to JavaScript and am wonder how to send details in email after validation ,heres my code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

 var compName=false;
 var compContry=false;
 var compsub=false;
 var compphone=false;
 var compemail=false;


function validate_form(form)
{
    if(compName)
    {
        document.getElementById('country').focus();
        compName=true;
        if(compContry)
        {
            document.getElementById('subject').focus();
            compContry=true;
            if(compsub)
            {
                document.getElementById('Phone').focus();
                compsub=true;
                if(compphone)
                {
                    document.getElementById('email').focus();
                    compphone=true;
                    if(compemail)
                    {

                        //I just use alert to show it works. 
                        alert("Your Details Are Sent ");
                        compemail=true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        document.getElementById('email').focus();
                        compemail=false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById('Phone').focus();
                    compphone=false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById('subject').focus();
                compsub=false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('country').focus();
            compContry=false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('username').focus();
        compName=false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Use your server side code to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send emal using Javascript.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296402/send-emal-using-javascript) and [others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+send+email)

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of server-side scripting to send emails.

Answer (score 0):

After it passes validation you can submit your form like this

```
document.formname.submit();
```

in your case, this goes at the end of your function

```
if (comP... == true) {
   form.submit();
}
```

Comment: do i not need to put in the email address to where i'm sending it ?

Comment: that goes in your html form tag `<form method='post' action='send.php'>` the code to send the email will be handled by your server, javascript will only do the first layer of validation

Comment: @martin, see the other answers that say you need to send mail server-side. The closest you can come to sending mail via javascript would be to use the HTML "mailto" command. You could use it in the "action" attribute of the <form> tag. So, the submittal of a form like this <form action="mailto:you@yoursite.com"> will attempt to open the email client on the user's machine to allow them to send an email. You can control form submittal as indicated by Ibu above.

Comment: @lbu, hi i never usedphp before and am going to give it a try , i found this Script http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php and am just wondering can i put the php in the head of my page like JavaScript

Comment: @martin, ok since you havent used php [this is all](http://devzone.zend.com/article/627-PHP-101-PHP-For-the-Absolute-Beginner) i am going to give you and you are going to come back a pro

Answer (score 0):

you can add return false; after each validation if you are using cutom js
for example

```
var first_name = $("#first_name");
        if(!$.trim(first_name.val()).length) {
            first_name.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
            return false;
        }else{
            first_name.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success'); 
        }
```

return false will stop the submit button to proceed until the form is not filled.

[freelancer](http://www.freelancingdesign.com)