# Simply text-box value emailed to me (JQuery & HTML)

Tags: jquery, html, email

Im trying to find an ultra simple example that takes a single text box value, and emails it to an address that I specify when the user hits "submit"

The form would be something like this:

```
<form>
   <input type="text" name="emailAddy" value="Enter Your Email Address" size="25" />
   <input type="submit" value="Get Notified" />
</form>
```

On click, it should email the emalAddy field value to me...  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, You can't use plain jQuery and HTML to send emails. You need some sort of server side code to mail.

What you can do instead is, submit the form, extract the details on the server side and send the email. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415205/how-to-send-email-by-using-javascript-or-jquery) and links given there might be of help.

Answer (score 1):

the closest you can do to send an email on the client-side is using mailto:email@adress.com, the same issue was addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120991/send-email-after-validation/6121055#6121055)

For sending emails you need a server-side interaction

Answer (score 0):

You could use some javascript to feed the textbox value to a mailto: link...see syntax [here](http://www.ianr.unl.edu/internet/mailto.html). Then you don't even have to code the server side...their mail client does the work.