# Send email via HTML from predefined emailID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a feedback form which consist of 5 fields like name,contact Number etc, and a button to send. I want whenever user inputs the field and hits send button an email containing the values from these fields should be sent to a particular mail id bur "FROM MY DEFINED" mail address, I dont want mailto option as it allows the user to send email from his account.
I know this with ASP.NET but i need with simple HTML or javascript or jquery.

Please Help.
Thank You

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: What is currently accepting the output from the 'send' button?

Comment: @PassKit — Presumably nothing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to send email by using javascript or jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415205/how-to-send-email-by-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You **need** a server side technology to send email.

If you want to use JavaScript, then there are [a number of packages for sending email in npm](https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/smtp). (Note this is *server side* JavaScript, the browser doesn't provide any tools that you can use for this).

The closest you can get to submitting form data over email with just common client side technologies is the [`mailto:` scheme](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html) which:

- You have already rejected
- Doesn't work most of the time anyway