# Add custom text to Sharepoint Email Alert

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-list

We have an alert set-up for sharepoint list, but I want to add some custom text to the alert email. We do not have any access to SPD or sharepoint server and can make changes to sharepoint client only.

Can anyone please advice?

Comment: The SharePoint 'client' - whats that exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that sends out emails runs on the SharePoint server via the Timer Job. Since you have no access to do anything with the server **you've got absolutely no chance** of modifying the built in alert emails.

*Could you do this with javascript?*

You can't send emails with JavaScript directly. You can open up a draft [email in a users default email client using a mailto link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/send-email-with-javascript) but this won't achieve what you want as a user will still have to edit it.

You could, I suppose, put some javascript onto an edit page using a content editor web part (which you can do without SPD) to on changes make an [AJAX call to a separate web server to do the actual sending.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415205/how-to-send-email-by-using-javascript-or-jquery)