# JQuery - send email using textarea in dialog

Tags: jquery, email, dialog

I'm trying to pop up a dialog containing a text area for the email content.

This code pops up the dialog when the first button is clicked, but I'm having no luck getting the "send email" button to do anything.

```
<body>
    <button id="myButton">Click for the dialog!</button>
</body>

<div id="myDialog" title="Reply">    

    <textarea id="myTextarea">Some initial text</textarea>

    <button id="emaiSubmit" onclick="emailButtonClicked()">Send Email</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function emailButtonClicked() {
    alert('Clicked');
}

$("#myDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false
});

$("#myButton").button().click(function() {
    $("#myDialog").dialog("open");
});
```

Ultimately, I'd like to capture the textarea's final text, close the dialog, and send the email with Ajax. But the first step is to get the "Send Email" button to execute some code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to send email by using javascript or jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415205/how-to-send-email-by-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<body>
  <button id="myButton">Click for the dialog!</button>
</body>

<div id="myDialog" title="Reply">    

    <textarea id="myTextarea">Some initial text</textarea>

    <button id="emaiSubmit">Send Email</button>
```

```
$(function(){

    function emailButtonClicked() {
        alert('Clicked');
    }    
    $("#myDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });

    $("#myButton").on("click",function(){

        $("#myDialog").dialog("open");   
    });

    $("#emaiSubmit").on("click",emailButtonClicked);

});
```

Comment: Can you explain why this version works and mine doesn't? I'd like to learn something, not just get it working.

Comment: BTW, the jsfiddle doesn't match your answer and doesn't work.

Comment: In the JSfiddle example I have commented out the code to open the dialogue box.