# Sending email from custom email address in jQuery

Tags: jquery, email, outlook

I am aware that we can send mail using jQuery by `mailto`function and send the mail from outlook. By default it will take the from address as the account logged into outlook.

How can we customize the from address by jQuery, so that while opening the mail in outlook, a user specifies mail address should be populated in From address?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `mailto` is html and has nothing to do with jquery

Comment: Also you can't change the from address in outlook - you can only send emails from any account you have set up in outlook, otherwise people would be able to just spam and send emails from spoof accounts

Answer (score 0):

mailto is **no** function of jquery not javascript, it is a html link and your browser opens your default mail program if you press it!

You can not do this with a mailto, you have to write both a E-Mail script (eg. in PHP) and use jQuery.post.

[See how to here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415205/how-to-send-email-by-using-javascript-or-jquery)