# Pulling the value of a form "select" and use it in the "action" of the form

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use the dropdown box to choose the correct first part of the e-mail to send it to.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script language="JavaScript">
    <!-- \/ Not sure if this part is formatted right \/ -->
    var mailpre = ("MAILTO:" + document.getElementById("cusub").value + "@cmputers.ca");
     <!-- /\ Not sure if this part is formatted right /\ -->
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- \/ Not sure if the action part is formatted right \/ -->
  <form action=mailpre method="post" enctype="text/plain" autocomplete="on" id="contact">
    <!-- /\ Not sure if the action part is formatted right /\ -->
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Contact Information</legend>
      Name:
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="clientname" autofocus required>
      <br>E-mail:
      <br>
      <input type="email" name="clientemail" required>
      <br>Telephone Number:
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="clientphone">
      <br>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Subject</legend>
      <select id="cusub" name="subject">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="booking">Booking An Appointment</option>
        <option value="support">Technical Support</option>
        <option value="feedback">Feedback</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </fieldset>
  </form>


</body>

</html>
```

Hopefully someone can help, as it seems screwy to me.

Comment: What exactly your question ?

Comment: you didnot get selected value?

Comment: var e = document.getElementById("cusub");
var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;   and use text in mailto

Answer (score 0):

To change form `action` attribute with `select` :

```js
function premail(){
  document.getElementById('contact').setAttribute('action', "mailto:" + document.getElementById("cusub").value + "@cmputers.ca");
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" enctype="text/plain" autocomplete="on" id="contact">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Contact Information</legend>
      Name:
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="clientname" autofocus required>
      <br>E-mail:
      <br>
      <input type="email" name="clientemail" required>
      <br>Telephone Number:
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="clientphone">
      <br>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Subject</legend>
      <select id="cusub" onchange="premail()" name="subject">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="booking">Booking An Appointment</option>
        <option value="support">Technical Support</option>
        <option value="feedback">Feedback</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

P.S.: You **can not send email using JavaScript alone**. You'd need a server-side handler to connect with the SMTP server to actually send the mail.

Read details in this thread:

[How to send email by using javascript or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415205/how-to-send-email-by-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting `action` attribute. Use `FORMELEMENT.action` to set the `action` property.

Note: Place your script as a `last child` of the `body` or inside `window.onload` hander otherwise it will not be accessible by `DOM API`

**Edit:** To update `action` attribute on every `change` event, use `.addEventListener('change'`

```js
var setActionValue = function(value) {
  var mailpre = ("MAILTO:" + value + "@cmputers.ca");
  document.getElementById('contact').action = mailpre;
  alert(document.getElementById('contact').action);
};
document.getElementById('cusub').addEventListener('change', function() {
  setActionValue(this.value);
});
setActionValue(document.getElementById('cusub').value);
```

```html
<form action=mailpre method="post" enctype="text/plain" autocomplete="on" id="contact">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Contact Information</legend>
    Name:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="clientname" autofocus required>
    <br>E-mail:
    <br>
    <input type="email" name="clientemail" required>
    <br>Telephone Number:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="clientphone">
    <br>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Subject</legend>
    <select id="cusub" name="subject">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="booking">Booking An Appointment</option>
      <option value="support">Technical Support</option>
      <option value="feedback">Feedback</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/d1quzh7b/1/)