# How to send a mail by jQuery using internal SMTP server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, email, smtp

I have the internal SMTP server available with me which is internal to the organisation.
I want to send a mail using jQuery with this server.

It doesn't require any username or password to send a mail.

And hostname looks like mxtest.orgname.com

Can any one help me with the code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you search about this before you make your question? If  so you might would have found something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415205/how-to-send-email-by-using-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: There's a package `nodemailer` with which can send mail from a node environment. I'm not sure whether it is possible from the client.

Comment: Maybe this post will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415205/how-to-send-email-by-using-javascript-or-jquery/1415230

Comment: Maybe this service could work for you https://smtpjs.com - be careful what you expose to the user, since it's client-side javascript